# Weird result with plot option type="b". Why does this happen?

Tags: r, plot

The following works, giving 3 points connected with a line.

```
plot(c(1,7,12), c(0,0,2),type="b")
```

However this does not work (it plots the points but without connecting line and without any warning or error)

```
t<-data.frame(x=1:20,y=c(0,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  0, NA, NA, NA, NA,  2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
plot(t$x, t$y,type="b")
```

Why is that? Is it because of the `NA` in the data frame? I can't seem to find any reference on this.

Comment: Excel, LibreOffice as well as other plotting software IGNORES NA, which is not unreasonable. Get a life instead of trolling arround here. I have marked your comment as offensive because it is so.

Comment: @mdsumner- that's a bit harsh, the documentation of the NA plotting is referenced in ?lines, not ?plot, which would mean it wouldn't be entirely unreasonable to have missed it. It also wouldn't be unreasonable to expect that R might print a warning message if it encounters NA's in a plot. Such a warning might be helpful in the instance of a `points()` statement where it might not be immediately obvious that some points were NA's and were not plotted (if not entered directly). It's no drama to me that it doesn't, but I struggle to see how the above points means this is 'not a real question.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the intended, documented, and (when you need to plot lines with breaks in them) *desirable* behavior of R's `lines()` function. From the `?lines` help page:

> The coordinates can contain ‘NA’ values. If a point contains ‘NA’
>        in either its ‘x’ or ‘y’ value, it is omitted from the plot, and
>        lines are not drawn to or from such points.  Thus missing values
>        can be used to achieve breaks in lines.

To get lines between the points, simply remove the points for which `y` has a value of `NA`:

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:20, 
              y=c(0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))

plot(y ~ x, data = d, type = "b", subset = !is.na(y))
```

Answer (score 3):

R doesn't plot points that are NA, nor does it plot connections between points that have NAs separating them.

If you have NAs in your vector and you want R to skip them, one solution is to get rid of those rows:

```
d<-data.frame(x=1:20,y=c(0,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  0, NA, NA, NA, NA,  2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
d2 <- d[!(is.na(df$y)), ]
plot(d2$x, d2$y, type="b")
```

(Also, `t` is not a good name for an R variable since it is already a function in R, one that transposes matrices).

Comment: Not a criticism *at all*, but people (me included) often make that warning about using `t` or `c` as variable names --- and then instead name their data.frames `df`, which is **also** a function in base R. (Again, I'm included). Maybe the take home message, then, is that you shouldn't name your own *functions* `t` or `c` or `df`, etc., but that it's actually pretty harmless to name other types of objects with those same names? (At least in interactive use, or if you aren't using functions like `get()` to find the functions that you'll be executing.)

Comment: Haha! Excellent point- I actually wasn't aware of the `df` function. You also make a great point- being used to Python, I frequently forget that functions and variables can share the same names in R.

Comment: Yeah, it's something I just realized myself. Also, an interesting point about the difference between Python and R. Maybe the main issue is really that having objects named `c` and `t` hurts code readability, since they are so familiar and frequently used, whereas most folks don't use `df` to get the density function of the F distribution in their day-to-day use of R, so it's safe to use *it* without confusion.